# Error while running blazor app in debug mode

Tags: .net, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

When I try to run the default blazor solution with 3 projects the client-side, server-side and shared project in debug mode I get the error as shown in the image. If I run it using ctrl+F5 ie not in debug mode it works fine. Also, my debug breakpoints are not getting hit.

[image: This is the error when I try to run blazor app which has 3 projects client, Server and shared which is the default project created when run in debug mode]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the browser windows where the project was previously launched are closed. This usually fixes the issue for me. You can also try deleting the cache and other data in the browser, and try another browser.